# insert into mysql database without refreshing page using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i try to insert some data into a mysql db table without refreshing page 
so i write this script to send the data to a php page that contain the query that will be executed by clicking the submit button the success function is executed ""the input feilds become empty "" but the php file seem to be not executed

```
   <?php
    $idst=$_GET['idst'];
    $idusr = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $auth_user->viewReservations($idst,$idusr);
    ?>
    <!--******* add reservation ******-->    
    <tr>     
      <form >
            <td><input required type="text" id="client" name="title"></td>
            <td><input required type="text" id="tel" name="tel"></td>
            <td><input required type="date" id="start" placeholder="yy-MM-dd" 
            name="start"></td>
            <td><input required type="date" id="end" placeholder="yy-MM-dd" 
            name="end"></td>  
            <td><input required type="number" id="prix" name="prix"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type ="submit" id="submit_reservation" class="btn btn-
 info" 
            name="submit" value="ajouter" style="width: 70px"></td>
            <td></td>
       </form>
          </tr>
         </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_reservation").click(function()
    {
    var client =$("#client").val();
    var tel =$("#tel").val();
    var start =$("#start").val();
    var end =$("#end").val();
    var prix =$("#prix").val();
    var idst=<?php echo json_encode($idst); ?>;
    var idusr=<?php echo json_encode($idusr); ?>;
    $. ajax(
    {
    url: "addreserv.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: {
    "done": 1,
    "client" :client,
    "tel" : tel,
    "start": start,
    "end": end,
    "prix":prix,
    "idst":idst,
    "idusr":idusr
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
    $("#client").val('');
    $("#tel").val('');
    $("#start").val('');
    $("#end").val('');
    $("#prix").val('');
    }
    })
    });
    });
    </script>
```

and this is the php file to execute the query using the data sended from this page

```
<?php
/*require_once("session.php");*/
require_once("class.user.php");
if (isset($_POST['done']))
{
$adder = new USER();
$client=$_POST['client'];
$tel=$_POST['tel'];
$start=$_POST['start'];
$end=$_POST['end'];
$prix=$_POST['prix'] ;
$idst=$_post['idst'];
$idusr = $_POST['idusr'];
$adder->addReservation($client,$tel,$start,$end,$prix,$idst,$idusr);
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error in console??

Comment: `submit` type does not have a click event

Comment: set return in your ` returnedresult = $adder->addReservation...`  that check if data inserted or not , then in `addreserv.php type` at the end `echo returnedresult`;  then ajax call set  `console.log(data)` and see result in console

Comment: You neglected to cancel the event default action in your submit handler, so the browser submits the form the "normal" way ... and since you did not specify an action for the form, in this case it means it will simply “reload” the page.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile `$("#submit_reservation").click(function()` is the click you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add a id to the form and prevent the form submit.

```
<tr>     
  <form id="reservation_form">
        <td><input required type="text" id="client" name="title"></td>
        <td><input required type="text" id="tel" name="tel"></td>
        <td><input required type="date" id="start" placeholder="yy-MM-dd" 
        name="start"></td>
        <td><input required type="date" id="end" placeholder="yy-MM-dd" 
        name="end"></td>  
        <td><input required type="number" id="prix" name="prix"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type ="submit" id="submit_reservation" class="btn btn-info" 
        name="submit" value="ajouter" style="width: 70px"></td>
        <td></td>
   </form>
</tr>

$("#reservation_form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
... Your logic ...
```

}